# Unwrap Maybe values from nested records

Tags: purescript

I have a series of nested records of config information in PureScript that I want to pass to a JavaScript function. These records predominantly consist of `Maybe`-typed values. Is there a way I can serialize this to JavaScript objects which omit the `Nothing`-valued methods and unwrap the `Just`-valued methods?

I've [taken a shot](https://pastebin.com/sjVzSvnK) at writing this in JavaScript using semi-hacky `instanceof` checks, but it's been very painful, e.g. because there is no easy way to stop the recursion (I can't differentiate my records from random other JavaScript objects). Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the [`purescript-nullable`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-nullable/3.0.0/docs/Data.Nullable) package. You can turn `Maybe` values into `Nullable` values using `toNullable :: forall a. Maybe a -> Nullable a`. The resulting runtime representation is appropriate for passing to JavaScript functions, since `toNullable (Just value)` becomes `value` during runtime and `toNullable Nothing` becomes `null` during runtime.

Another option is to use the [`purescript-simple-json`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-simple-json/4.0.0/docs/Simple.JSON) package. You can use the `write :: forall a. WriteForeign a => a -> Foreign` function to turn a record with `Maybe` values into a record where `Just value` is replaced with `value` and `Nothing` is replaced with `undefined`. This approach should more straightforward for your use case of nested records with `Maybe` values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`genericEncodeJson`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-argonaut-generic-codecs/6.0.4/docs/Data.Argonaut.Generic.Encode#v:genericEncodeJson) from `Data.Argonaut` and set the `omitNothingFields` flag to `true`. This flag does exactly what you expect.

```
module Main where

import Prelude

import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (logShow)
import Data.Argonaut.Generic.Aeson (options)
import Data.Argonaut.Generic.Encode (Options(..), genericEncodeJson)
import Data.Generic (class Generic)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))

data TheRecord = TheRecord { a :: Maybe Int, b :: Maybe String, c :: String }
derive instance gRecord :: Generic TheRecord

main = 
    -- Prints {"c":"Always here","a":42}
    logShow $ genericEncodeJson (Options o { omitNothingFields = true }) rec
    where
        rec = TheRecord { a: Just 42, b: Nothing, c: "Always here" }
        Options o = options
```